# Using socket io without returning the index.html throws an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I would like to setup websocket without necessarily having to return the index.html file

Am still new to the socket io and this is what i have tried

installed socket io via

```
npm install socket.io --save
```

created index.js

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');


  // Loading socket.io
 var io = require('socket.io');

  // When a client connects, we note it in the console
  io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
   console.log('A client is connected!');
 });


 server.listen(1100);
```

Now when i run node index am getting an error

```
   io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
      ^

  TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
```

What am trying to do is connect the websocet to my vuejs client side so ive skipped the part to display html part since i dont want to display html but to use the socket events.
where am i going wrong?

Comment: Hi, by looking at the documentation, looks like you might need to do the following:
`var io = require('socket.io')(http); io.on('connection', function () {}); : example link: https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Answer (score 0):

Hey you need to attach socket.io to an http server for your code to work and listen to incoming events.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

//io.on is the shorter form of io.sockets.on
io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('user connected');
});
```